# If $T$ is compact normal and injective then there exists a unitary $U$, and a positive $S$ such that $T=US=SU$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T \in B(H)$ a compact normal
> and injective linear operator. Prove that there exists a unitary $U\in
>  B(H)$, and a positive (non-negative) $S\in B(H)$ such that $T=US=SU$.

Using the spectral theorem (since $T$ is compact and normal in a separable Hilbert space), one can show that there exists a unitary $U$ and a diagonal $S$ (with complex eigenvalues on the diagonal) such that $S=UTU^*$. This gets me 'close', but how can I continue from here? Obviously, I haven't used the injectivity of $T$, but I don't see how to use it to obtain the result. I thought perhaps Fredholm's alternatives might be useful, but haven't been able to connect the dots.

Any ideas? (also - if you could please share the thought process that led you to your ideas that would be very helpful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(a) The compactness of $T$ is irrelevant. As $T$ is injective, so is $T^*,$ by normality.
Therefore the ranges of $T$ and $T^*$ are dense.
Applying polar decomposition gives $T=U|T|,$ where $U$ is a partial isometry between ${\rm Im}\,|T|$ and ${\rm Im}\,T.$ The range of $|T|$ is dense, because $\ker|T|=\ker T=\{0\}.$ Hence $\ker U=\{0\}$ and ${\rm Im}\,U\supset {\rm Im}\,T.$ Therefore $U$ is a unitary operator. Moreover
$$|T|=U^{-1}T,\qquad |T|=T^*U$$
Hence $$|T|^2=U^{-1}TT^*U =U^{-1}T^*TU=U^{-1}|T|^2U$$
Thus $U$ commutes with $|T|^2.$ Therefore $U$ commutes with $|T|,$ as $|T|$ can be represented by a power series with terms depending on $|T|^2.$
Finally
$$UT=U^2|T|=U|T|U=TU$$
(b) For a compact normal operator by the spectral theorem there exists an orthonormal system $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^N,$ $N\le \infty,$ and complex nonzero numbers $\{\lambda_n\}_{n=1}^\infty,$ such that
$$Tx=\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle\, e_n$$
As $T$ is injective the system $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^N$ must constitute an orthonormal basis in $H,$ and $H$ should be separable (i.e. the orthonormal basis is countable). If $H$ is finite dimensional then $N<\infty,$ otherwise $N=\infty.$

Let $\lambda_n=u_n|\lambda_n|,$ where $|u_n|=1.$ Define the operators $S$ and $U$ by
$$Sx=\sum_{n=1}^N |\lambda_n|\,\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n,\qquad Ux=\sum_{n=1}^N u_n\,\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n $$
Then $S$ is a positive operator and $U$ is a unitary one. Moreover $T=US=SU.$

The solution (b) makes use of the polar decomposition of complex numbers.

Comment: Is there a way to replace the polar decomposition with something that perhaps uses the compactness? I haven't learned polar decomposition.

Comment: Are you familiar with (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346482/spectral-theorem-of-compact-operators-in-hilbert-space

Comment: Yes - the spectral decomposition (it's also what I mentioned in my post that I thought of using but couldn't get a unitary as required).

Comment: Ok, I will add another explanation maliny use of the spectral theorem.

Comment: That would be very helpful as I haven't yet been able to adapt it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a fruitful direction, but the way we proved the spectral decomposition for normal compact operators was via a decomposition $T=T_1+iT_2$ where, since $T$ is compact then so are $T_i$ and are also self-adjoint and therefore normal. The reason I thought this could be helpful was since they also satisfy: $T_1T_2=T_2T_1$ since $T$ is normal. Still can't see how this helps much though.

Comment: I have added an alternative solution. Hopefully it is clear.

Comment: Yes - thank you for all the help!